# Badge on bottomNavigationView padding or margin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

How can we set `margin` to badge of `bottomNavigation` material component??

OR

How can we prevent to `padding` when we click on an item in `bottomNavigationView` because of that a little of badge will be hidden as we see in these pictures.

When item 1 is `unSelected` :

[image]

When item 1 `isSelected` (a little of badge height will be hidden):

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the method **`setVerticalOffset`**:

```
  BadgeDrawable badge = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);
  badge.setNumber(...);
  badge.setVerticalOffset(20);  //The dimension is in pixel
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

If it covers the icon you can also use the method `setHorizontalOffset`:

```
badge.setHorizontalOffset(-10);
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.2.0-alpha01`

Comment: Oh thanks , i think i used 1.2.0 version let me check the 1.2.0-alpha version.

Comment: @miladsalimi You can use the 1.2.0-beta01.

Comment: Thanks , then you merged https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/630